# Missing data when reading URI from NFC tag

Tags: android, tags, uri, nfc, ndef

I've created a NFC read/write part of my application code, where:

READ is responsible for processing data and triggering a web browser:

```
ndef.connect()
val ndefMessage = ndef.ndefMessage
if (ndefMessage.records != null && ndefMessage.records.isNotEmpty()) {
   message = String(it.records[0].payload)
}
ndef.close()
```

WRITE writes a URL onto the NFC tag:

```
ndef.connect()
val mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(url)
ndef.writeNdefMessage(NdefMessage(mimeRecord))
ndef.close()
```

For some mysterious reason when I write the URL "http://www.google.com", my my `message` variable (after reading a tag with that URL) contains only "google.com". I have no idea why the rest of the URL ("http://www.") is removed/ommited. Can you tell me what is going on? Where is my mistake?

Comment: To clarify, you are writing the variable `url` to the tag, which has the value `http://www.google.com`, and when you read it, the return is just `google.com`? Have you tried any other url's? It might be helpful to see where url is created.

Comment: Yea at the moment it works exacly as you wrote. Yes I did try different URLs - no difference tho :C I read the URL from `EditText` widget and pass it to my `TagManager`

Comment: I can't put this down as an answer, as it's more of a theory, but NFC information has to be short and concise. It's very possible that the Ndef library is shortening the URL on purpose, if it begins with `http://www`, as that's kind of the "default" URI.

Comment: url is not `http://www.google.com` ! if it would be it would work... createUri does normalize your string but it doesnt remove `http://www.` this is happening somewhere else. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createUri(android.net.Uri)

Comment: "Yea at the moment it works exacly as you wrote."  Okay im out of this discussion. If you dont even understand what you answer people its impossible to help you. Also you didnt understand the point of my comment anyway. Good luck with your issue! - this answer is related to a comment that has been deleted -

Comment: @Michael'kC'J. Wow. You posted a 4 word answer first and then edited it out. I am sorry but `google.com is not URL` does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to decode the payload of the NDEF record as simple text (UTF-8 encoded string):

```
message = String(it.records[0].payload)
```

However, you wrote the URL as an NFC Forum URI record:

```
NdefRecord.createUri(url)
```

Consequently, you need to interpret the URI record according to the NFC Forum URI Record Type Definition specification (avaibale from NFC Forum). The payload of such a URI record consists of one abbreviation byte (which you can use to lookup the URI prefix in a table of well-defined prefixes) and the URI suffix (UTF-8 encoded).

You could either parse the record payload on your own or let Android to the magic for you by using something like:

```
uriString = it.records[0].toUri()
```